# Doubt in negative sign of relative velocities of two objects in same directions and opposite directions

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, conventions

Consider the following examples.
case 1)Two objects traveling in same direction one A in the velocity say 50 mph and other B in the velocity 60 mph. If we calculate velocity of A with reference to B it will be Va - Vb = 50 - 60 = -10. The negative sign means A is 10 mph lagging than B. Is my understanding right?

Now in case 2) A and B traveling in opposite directions with same velocities as mentioned above. Now if we calculate velocity of B with reference to A. As B is traveling in the opposite direction it will be (-Vb -Va) = -(Va + Vb) = -110.

In case 3) when calculating relative velocity of A with reference to B will be (Va -(-Vb)) = Va + Vb= +110.

As both A and B are getting closer in both case 2 and 3 why it has to be negative sign in case 2 and why it was formulated like this?
Or my understanding of assigning sign is wrong? please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assign a consistent sign convention to your velocities. If A and B are moving in the same direction, assign a positive sign to both of their velocities. If they are moving in opposite directions, assign opposite signs to their velocities - but remember which one is which.

Next, remember that if we are calculating the velocity of one object relative to a second, we always subtract the velocity of the second from the velocity of the first. So the velocity of A relative to B will always be $v_A - v_B$. This is always true regardless of the signs of $v_A$ and $v_B$.

So if A and B are moving in the same direction with $v_A=50$ mph and $v_B = 60$ mph then the velocity of A relative to B is $v_A - v_B = 50 - 60 = -10$ mph. The negative sign means that the velocity of A relative to B is in the opposite direction to the velocities of A and B. Does this mean that A is getting closer to B or getting further away ? We don't know this unless we know the relative positions of A and B.

Now if A and B are moving in opposite directions we can say that $v_A=50$ mph and $v_B = -60$ mph; notice that we have assigned a positive sign to $v_A$ and a negative sign to $v_B$. To find the velocity of A relative to B we use the same formula  $v_A - v_B$, but this time $v_A - v_B = 50 - (-60) = 110$ mph. So the velocity of A relative to B is $110$ mph in the direction that A is moving (because this is our positive direction). Once again, we don't know if this means that A and B are getting closer together unless we know the relative positions of A and B.

Comment: How many rules must one introduce (and then remember) to avoid simply working with vectors and components?  The "law" is a vector equation (as are many laws in introductory physics) and students should learn how to manipulate such laws, early and often.

Comment: @BenH Yes, this is just addition of vectors in disguise - but we don't know if the  questioner has been introduced to vectors yet. I find your explanation quite confusing - for example, if your $V_A$ and $V_B$ are speeds and so always positive then $v_{ABx}$ is *not* always $V_A+V_B$.

Comment: It is if the $x$ axis is chosen to point along the velocity of object $A$ (and, as assumed, the velocities of objects A and B point in opposite directions).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "law" to guide your calculations.  The "law${}^*$ of relative velocity" is a vector equation that states
$$
\vec{v}_{AC} = \vec{v}_{AB} + \vec{v}_{BC} 
$$
where $\vec{v}_{AB}$ is the velocity vector of object A with respect to object B.  In your questions, the velocities all lie along a line (one-dimension), so you can call that line the $x$ axis and then write down the $x$-component equation of the vector equation above:
$$
v_{ACx} = v_{ABx} + v_{BCx} 
$$
So for your "cases (2) and (3)", let's choose the $x$ axis to point in the direction of object A's velocity vector.  The implicit "third object", C, is the ground/road: the original speeds are assumed to be with respect to the road.  Therefore:
\begin{align}
v_{ACx} &= v_{ABx} + v_{BCx} \\
+ V_A  &= v_{ABx} + (-V_B) \quad \rightarrow \quad v_{ABx} = V_A + V_B
\end{align}
where I've written the $x$-component of the velocity, e.g., $v_{ACx}$, in terms of the given speed of object A with respect to the road: $V_A = \left| \vec{v}_{AC} \right|$.

So, we find that the velocity of A with respect to B has a positive $x$ component, meaning that it points in the direction of travel of $A$.  The velocity of B with respect to A is found using the basic equality that:
$$
\vec{v}_{AB} = -\vec{v}_{BA}
$$
so $v_{BAx} = - \left(V_A + V_B\right)$.

Of course if you chose a different $x$ axis, e.g., pointing in the direction of B, then your signs would be reversed. Therefore it is important to:

- Draw a pictures showing the original vectors $\vec{v}_{AC}$ and $\vec{v}_{BC}$.
- Show your choice of axis and name it, so that your equations containing the "$x$" components have some meaning.
- Use the "law" in component notation and be careful to find the components with respect to your chosen axis.

In summary: the positive and negative signs have no meaning except with respect to your chosen axis.

${}^*$ - This "law" is not really fundamental, it just comes from the (time derivative of) the relationship of the position vectors of the three objects: $\vec{r}_{AC} = \vec{r}_{AB} + \vec{r}_{BC}$.